# Could not find a valid gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I'm a beginner to Ruby.
I follow the steps on http://rubyonrails.org/download and
 installed Ruby on rails and created a project called "Blog" by following the youtube tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ8_VOGj5H8

But whenever I used the command `rails s`, it will give an error:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integ
ration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `ge
m install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add
it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

This is happening to both of my laptop and PC, both are using Windows 7.
I tried to run the command `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`, but then I gives me the error.

```
C:\Users\Ouye\blog>gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any
repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter, activerecord-sq
lserver-adapter, activerecord-bq-adapter, activerecord-simpledb-adapter, activer
ecord-mysql2-adapter
```

I tried all of the alternatives above and update my bundle install, some of the alternatives works and some don't. After I tried all of the alternatives above and run "rails s", I still get the same error of telling me to install sqlite3 adapter.

**This is what my gem file looks like**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**And this is all bundles in the gem**

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  actionmailer (3.2.13)
  actionpack (3.2.13)
  activemodel (3.2.13)
  activerecord (3.2.13)
  activeresource (3.2.13)
  activesupport (3.2.13)
  arel (3.0.2)
  builder (3.0.4)
  bundler (1.3.5)
  coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
  erubis (2.7.0)
  execjs (1.4.0)
  hike (1.2.2)
  i18n (0.6.1)
  journey (1.0.4)
  jquery-rails (2.2.1)
  json (1.7.7)
  mail (2.5.3)
  mime-types (1.23)
  multi_json (1.7.3)
  polyglot (0.3.3)
  rack (1.4.5)
  rack-cache (1.2)
  rack-ssl (1.3.3)
  rack-test (0.6.2)
  rails (3.2.13)
  railties (3.2.13)
  rake (10.0.4)
  rdoc (3.12.2)
  sass (3.2.9)
  sass-rails (3.2.6)
  sprockets (2.2.2)
  thor (0.18.1)
  tilt (1.4.1)
  treetop (1.4.12)
  tzinfo (0.3.37)
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can solve my problem.

Answer (score 19):

You cannot install `activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` as a gem, because this adapter is included with ActiveRecord already. The problem is not in `activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`, but in that you don't have `sqlite3` as part of your Gem bundle (the error message tells us this at the end: "*sqlite3 is not part of the bundle.*")

To fix it, add it to your Gemfile first:

```
# in your Gemfile
gem 'sqlite3'
```

then run from command line:

```
$ bundle install
```

Ensure that `sqlite3` installs correctly and shows up in your Gem bundle, and everything should work.

Comment: gem 'sqlite3' is already in my gem file. When I run the command "bundle install", it tells me that "Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed", but sqlite3 is still missing from my Gem bundle

Comment: I agree to his last comment. I have platform :ruby do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end  in my gemfile and it installed gem sqlite3 gem. I was able to see it work from the readme examples in irb so I know that part is working. It's an old version of rails when sqlite3 was not a default. I would try using the latest version of rails. They included a sample app in there so you should have no prblem getting that to run. Good Luck.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue as you are presenting, and after a lot of trial and error, i found some simple steps to fix it.

First, add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
```

Then run in your console:

```
bundle install
```

And then you should proceed normally

Comment: Copy-pasting an answer is not really helpful, unless you're adding something new to the conversation.

Comment: It might seem copy-paste, but the above answer didn't used the gem version, which didn't worked for me until i added it. Just wanted to share the exact steps i did to fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.0 has problems with sqlite3 and can't run. If you need to use sqlite3 you'll have to downgrade to 1.9.3. I don't have the link to the documentation about this, but I know if you downgrade to 1.9.3 you'll be fine. I'll see if I can find the link.